# How do I use find to individually zip files in a directory?

Tags: find

I was expecting something like,

`find . -name "*.bor" -exec sh -c 'zip ???' sh {} +`

where the ??? are replaced with `$@` or similar.

The end result needs to look like,

- 1.bor.zip
- 2.bor.zip etc.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
find . -name '*.bor' -exec zip '{}.zip' '{}' ';'
```